# Sofia SIP not sending REGISTER refresh when using TCP transport

Tags: sip, restcomm, sofia-sip

I have noticed that when I changed transport from UDP to TCP in Sofia SIP stack for some reason the SIP registration refreshes are not sent. Only the first REGISTER is sent properly and then nothing.

On the other hand, with the exact same setup if I use UDP as transport I properly get the REGISTER refreshes without issues.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Best regards,
Antonis Tsakiridis